# Node.js sessions

Tags: node.js, session

Is it possible to manage sessions in Node.js and how? I mean exactly Node.js, not Express.js.

**About the application.** I use a static Node.js server and [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) server. On the front-end I have a simple [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). And only one moment makes me think about sessions: when the user refreshes page he/she receives a new socket.

So I have to tie up the "login status" with session, not socket.

---

I've found the npm module "msession". This looks simple, and should do the job. But there is one problem now. I have to get the request and response objects from the socket.

The request I've managed to get this way:

```
let req = socket.upgradeReq;
```

I've tried this variant for response, but as expected, it didn't work:

```
let res = {writeHead: {}};
```

How can I handle the response object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this [blogpost](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/sessions-and-cookies-in-node/) made my day.

To conclude, here's what I've received as a result:

```
const http = require('http');
const staticServer = require('node-static');
const WebSocketServer = new require('ws');
const session = require('sesh/lib/core').magicSession();

// WebSocket server
const webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: 8081});

// Create a node-static server instance to serve the './public' folder
const fileFolder = new staticServer.Server('./public');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  GLOBAL.session = request.session;
  request.addListener('end', function () {
    fileFolder.serve(request, response);
  }).resume();

}).listen(1337);

webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
  if( typeof(ws.session) === "undefined")
    ws.session = GLOBAL.session;
  /* Any logic here */
});

console.log("Static server created")
```

So, it's a working solution of the sockets-based application, that has a static file server and sessions.

The solution requires:

```
npm install --save node-static && npm install --save ws && npm install --save sesh
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin will help you [node-session](https://github.com/quorrajs/NodeSession), or this one [node-client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions).

Comment: Node-session looks exactly what i need, but somewhy I get an error during install. Node-client-sessions is express oriented.

Comment: What error did you get? `npm install node-session` works well.

Comment: `Build failed
npm WARN install:deasync deasync@0.0.10 install: node ./build.js
npm WARN install:deasync Exit status 1` Anyway I've found how to use node-client-sessions in pure node environment.