# Session variables are undefined out of the scope it is set to a value in nodejs

Tags: node.js, session-variables

I am using nodejs and I am trying to access a session variable in a route which is not the same route where the session variable is defined and set. It keeps telling me that the session variable is not defined!

This is where I set the session variable:

```
var http      = require('http');
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var urlencodedParser =  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var app = express();
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var session = require('express-session');


app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: "This_is_a_secret",
    resave: false,
}));


    app.post('/auth',urlencodedParser,function (req, res) {

        conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name="'+req.body.username+'" AND user_pass="'+req.body.password+'"',function(err,res1){
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error!");
                res.send('-2');
            }
            else{
                if(res1.length==0) {
                    console.log("No matching!");
                    res.send('-2');
                }
                else if(res1.length==1){
                    req.session.username = req.body.username; //This is my session variable
                    console.log("Successful login with: " + req.session.username); //This works fine
                    res.send('1');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the second route where I am trying to access req.session.username:

```
app.post('/privilage',urlencodedParser,function (req, res) {

console.log("privilage: " + req.session.username);  //Here is where I need to check and it says "undefined"

    if(!req.session.username){
        res.send('-2');
    }
    else res.send('1');
});
```

What is wrong exactly??

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Can you post you server.js or index.js file? where you added session middleware in express?

Comment: Also, on a side note, this code seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I edited my post for you. Thanks. Regarding the injections, I am planning to fix it later.

Comment: **Please See below Url May Be usefull for You**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828686/sessions-in-node-js/34333505#34333505

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use store to session. It's means that sessions store in memory and reset on application restart.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "This_is_a_secret",
    resave: false,
    store: ...
}));
```

Be sure that you don't restart application between login and check requests.

---

Also I recommend to make some changes in your code

```
conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name="'+req.body.username+'" AND user_pass="'+req.body.password+'"', function(err, qres){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error!", err.message);
        return res.send('-2'); // Maybe best way is res.status(401).end()?
    }

    if (qres.length == 0) {
        console.log("No matching!");
        return res.send('-2');
    }

    if (qres.length != 1) // unbelievable case, but check it
        throw new Error("Smth wrong");

    req.session.username = req.body.username; 
    console.log("Successful login with: " + req.session.username);                     
    res.send('1');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'll do those changes