# How to destroy the session (store)?

Tags: node.js, session, redis, session-cookies, back4app

For authentification I'm trying to understand, how sessions work. With help of [documentation of express session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and [Sessions in Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828686/sessions-in-node-js) I got it work.

Now I'm figuring out, what to do, that users can log out. In the documentation of express session is to read "The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment." They recommand a compatible session store.

I have choosen [connect-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis). [They](https://redis.io/) call it an "in-memory data structure store". Now I'm wondering, what is the difference between redis and the database, that I would like to use ([back4app](https://www.back4app.com)).

If I implement connect-redis

```
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const redis = require("redis").createClient();

let sess = {
    store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', 6379, client: redis }),
    secret: cryptoString,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1 * 60 * 1000,
    },
}

server.use(session(sess));
```

the user object from back4app stills undefined. (Without redis the user object exists.)

As mentioned I have tryed Parse.User.logOut(). It doesn't work. The console says Parse.User is null.

Please, explain

- what is the difference between back4app and redis? Do I need both?
- how do I enable log out?

For all with the same problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409433/how-to-get-the-sessiontoken-for-currentuser) is my other question in this context. It will help you to see the whole picture.

Comment: Hi! Parse Server already has an implementation of Session to manage your users, please check this documentation: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#validating-session-tokens--retrieving-current-user

Comment: To logout your users, please check this URL: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#deleting-sessions

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't understand the documention. I' m learning and need input like this [log in](https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/parse-login-javascript)

Comment: I can't find the comand getting the user object. req.???

Comment: To get the user, have you tried req.user?

Comment: yes, req.user is undefined.

Comment: In order to log out, you just need to call `Parse.User.logOut()`. Take a look in this link: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#current-user

Comment: @DaviMacêdo the console says Parse.User is null. Parse.User.logout() doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share how you are installing the Parse SDK?

Comment: I've just seen your other question and I noticed you are using Back4App from a Node.js application and you are requiring `parse/node` package to a var called back4app. So, In order to log out, you should call `back4app.logOut({ sessionToken });`

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, The console says: back4app.logout is not a function. with back4app.User.logout(...) I get no error... how can I test, if the logout is successful? I have assumed, the session would be deleted on back4app.com. That's not the case.

Comment: Sorry. I sent it wrong to you before. The right would be `back4app.User.logOut({ sessionToken });`. The session that you passed should be deleted from the database. Other sessions from the same user can continue existing. Can you try to clean the session collection and do a test 1 - log in 2 - check if there is only one session 3 - log out 4 - test if there is no session?

Comment: just to be clear, `sessionToken` should be a var containing the session token that you want to destroy: `back4app.User.logOut({ sessionToken: yourSessionToken });`

Comment: thanks, logout works as expected with back4app.User.logOut({ sessionToken: yourSessionToken });