# How to get the sessionToken for currentUser?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, back4app

I work on a web app hosted on heroku. As database I try to use back4app. With help of the [back4app documention](https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/parse-login-javascript) I have realized the log in. Since two days I try to get the session to work with it.

Therefore I have read a lot of blogs, articels and of course the [parse documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#current-user). But I'm not able to get it to work. I hope, you will find my problem. Following code is my lastest attempt:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const back4app = require('parse/node');

back4app.initialize("xxx","yyy"); 
back4app.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';


server.use(express.static('web'));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.get('/lgn', (req, resp) => {
console.log("server.get('/lgn',...");
    resp.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/web/login.html'));
});

server.post('/lgn', (req, resp) => {
    const data =  req.body;

    console.log("server.post('/lgn',...");

    if(data.email != undefined){
        console.log(data.email);
        resetPassword(data);
    } else{
        logIn(data, function(err, user){
            console.log(user.get("sessionToken")); 


            //How to get the user object in other routes?
            console.log('session');
            back4app.User.enableUnsafeCurrentUser(); //is this a secure solution?

            back4app.User.currentAsync().then(function(userObj) {
                console.dir(userObj.get("sessionToken"));
            });

            if(user){
                resp.send( JSON.stringify( {url: '/'}) );
            } else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});


function logIn(data, cb) {
    // Create a new instance of the user class
    var user = back4app.User
        .logIn(data.username, data.password)
            .then(function(user) {
                console.log('User successful logged in with name: ' +     user.get("username"));
                cb(null, user);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                cb(error);
    });
}


server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
});
```

The userObj is null. But why? What I have to do, that I get the currentUser and his session in other routes?

(I have also tryed to work with back4app.Session, but didn't get, what I want.)

Answer (score 2):

It is unsafe to use the `currentUser` methods in a Node.js app.

Instead of:

```
logIn(data, function(err, user){
            console.log(user.get("sessionToken")); 


            //How to get the user object in other routes?
            console.log('session');
            back4app.User.enableUnsafeCurrentUser(); //is this a secure solution?

            back4app.User.currentAsync().then(function(userObj) {
                console.dir(userObj.get("sessionToken"));
            });

            if(user){
                resp.send( JSON.stringify( {url: '/'}) );
            } else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Use:

```
logIn(data, function(err, user){
            // This is your session token. You will have to send it back to your client. The client should store it and send it to the server in the other routes.
            const sessionToken = user.get("sessionToken");
            console.log(sessionToken); 


            //How to get the user object in other routes?
            //In order to get the user in other routes you will have to use the sessionToken like this:
            back4app.User.me({ sessionToken }).then(function(userObj) {
                console.dir(userObj.get("sessionToken"));
            });

            if(user){
                resp.send( JSON.stringify( {url: '/'}) );
            } else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: In addition to the answer, I wanted to let you know that you can use the Back4App API directly from your frontend code. I mean... you don't even need the Node.js application running on Heroku for most of the cases.

Comment: Thank you @DaviMacêdo, my hero. back4app.User.me( sessionToken ).then(...).chache(...) works ... A last question for this. In which documentation I could have found this? On https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/ I can't find this.

Comment: It was actually added to the SDK very recently and no docs were written about it yet. I will make sure it will be added to the docs.